# PHP and Excel sheet

Tags: php

this is code to retrive data and insert it in to excel sheet

```
header( "Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel" );
header( "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" );
header('Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8');
header( "Content-disposition: attachment; filename=spreadsheet.xls" );

$rs = mysql_query("select * from organizations");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($rs)) {

    echo $row->name1 . "\t" . $row->name2 . "\t" . $row->name3 ."\t" . $row->email . "\n";
}
```

($row->name1) is in arabic format

the problem is in excel sheet Arabic language is unreadable

any solution please

Comment: Why are you overwriting the `Content-type` header 3 times? And presenting a tab-separated file with a `.xls` extension?

Comment: 1) You send twice the `Content-Type` header.
2) This is not an Excel spreadsheet. It's actually a tab delimited file (`\t` sequence). I'm not sure if there's a way to "code" the codepage in a file like this. This is why you get unreadable text. If you try to import it, using the Arabic codepage, I'm sure you'll read it fine.

Comment: No it isn't, it's badly written code to generate a tsv file - use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php), and use the correct content type headers - which isn't text/HTML

Comment: Check you character encoding

Comment: Don't do CSV. It breaks in Excel when you have Excel in different languages. Use a decent XLS(X) generator. They exist.

Answer (score 0):

their being some 3rd party tools for reading Microsoft Word/Excel files, but as aforementioned, the best is to export as CSV.

Comment: Beg to differ - best solution isn't CSV because you can have problems with opening in MS Excel because of Excel's locale settings, and because it's difficult to work with non-ASCII charsets in CSV. Best solution is to create A BIFF format xls file or an OfficeOpenXML xlsx file that can eliminate these problems